# Display all rows of same value if either of row matches a where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been sitting for so long on this! Sorry I'm pretty new to this. Do have a look at this image

[image]

My requirement is:

If `BaseItem = APO_Product` I would like to show all the rows of `NLLLFLF02`. When all the rows that validate the `where` condition, I would like to delete the ones that don't match. I have been trying this for long but nothing has worked out to me. HELP!!.

Table Name:`W93zE8Z8`.

I would like this to be my output:

[image]

Comment: Sql or MySql..?

Comment: You want only row no 3 and 8 ?

Comment: @Ergis the dbms is taged as MySQL, there is nothing wrong with the tags

Comment: Please remove the image and add the data as text

Comment: @Ergis, SQL is a _language_ supported by many different products, of which MySQL is one.

Comment: Also show us the expected result. (As properly formatted text, no image.)

Comment: @ErgestBasha people use the `sql`, wanting to actually mean `sql server` (which is a mistake). I know, and they don't. Thats why I asked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If BaseItem = APO_Product I would like to show all the rows of NLLLFLF02. When all the rows that validate the where condition, I would like to delete the ones that don't match.

It seems that you need in

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM W93zE8Z8 t1
LEFT JOIN W93zE8Z8 t2 ON t1.GROUP_4 = t2.GROUP_4
                     AND t2.BaseItem = t2.APO_Product
WHERE t2.GROUP_4 IS NULL
```